# How to manage domain url?

Tags: url, heroku, dns

I have my site on heroku pccma.herokuapp.com. I have a domain brianlau.tech. When I go to brianlau.tech, it gets redirected to pccma.herokuapp.com. How can I get my domain url to replace my site?

Here are my settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, I added on heroku. Any help would be appreciated! [image]

Answer (score 1):

I looks to me like your A records are incorrect, and need to be changed to the Herkou IP's.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: I looked at that guide. I can't find my heroku site IP anywhere.

It directs just fine, but how do I mask the heroku url?